# Qserialport on Beaglebone Black

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I'm running a BBB with debian, kernel 3.8. I've got Qt up and running, I can do a simple hello world program on it. Everything works great.

My host machine is running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

I'm trying to install the qserialport library, but its giving me a lot of grief. I've tried following the wiki [here](http://wiki.qt.io/QtSerialPort#e290b0f94383a96ecdf7f6b720b72092).

Running from the command line seems promising, but I'm not sure how to resolve the error that I'm seeing. When I've run the qmake successfully, but when I run the make command I run into the error: `arm-linux-bnueabihf/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev`.

I have libudev-dev installed in my host computer, so I don't think this is the problem.

Any thoughts on what might be the problem or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, `libudev-dev` is package with header files. And `-ludev` is about linking with actual `udev` library (`.so` or `.a` file). Next, when cross-compiling with ARM toolchain (using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` toolchain, in your case), you should provide mentioned library built for the same architecture (ARM), and not for your host PC. So it seems like you need to build (or download already built) `udev` for ARM architecture first, and then "feed" it to your `qmake` file, or something like that.

Comment: Have you already looked at other Linux distros? One option is [Buildroot](http://buildroot.org/). It provides both [support for BBB](http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/configs/beaglebone_defconfig) and Qt4/5 including QSerialPort support. As alternative you can also take Debian, debootstrap and [multi-arch](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/jessie/sect.manipulating-packages-with-dpkg.html#sect.multi-arch) approach.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to do this with a shout out to Sam in the comments above.

I cheated a little and copied the libraries that I needed from the Beaglebone Black to my host computer and put them in the folder that contained all cross-compiled Qt libraries. As I found out later on, I also would need to to this with the tslib libraries as well (I have enabled Qt with touchscreen support).

These steps allowed me to at least complete the `make` command of the serialport library.

I then used the `sudo make install` command to install the library, with no problems there.

Running a program with the serial port library was also causing problems. I cheated again and used `scp -r /opt/qt-arm/lib root@beagleboneblacknetworkip:/usr/` to copy my entire cross-compiled qt library from my host machine over to the Beaglebone Black. Copying that directory over got me up and running.